# Kendo UI add new record

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created a odata v4 service using web API 2.2, I have successfully bound the service records to grid but i am unable to add the records. Please note that i created a separate project for odata v4 service and Kendo UI Grid is in other project. Below is the code for grid.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchResults").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        type: "odata-v4",
        transport: {
          read:
            "http://test.odata.northwind/odata/Customers",
          create: {
            url: "http://test.odata.northwind/odata/Customers",
            dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
            type: "post"
          },
          parameterMap: function (data, type) {
            if (type == "create") {
              // send the created data items as the "models" service parameter encoded in JSON
              return {models: kendo.stringify(data.models)};
            }
          }
        },
        pageSize: 20,

        schema: {
          data: "value",
          model: {
            id: "CustomerID",/*
                                total: function (data) { return data['@@odata.count']; }*/
            fields: {

              CustomerID: {type: "string"},
              CompanyName: {type: "string"},
              ContactName: {type: "string"},
              ContactTitle: {type: "string"},
              Country: {type: "string"}
            }
          }
        }

      },
      columns: [{
        field: "CustomerID",
        title: "CustomerID",
        filterable: {
          cell: {
            showOperators: false
          }
        }

      },


        {
          field: "ContactName",
          title: "Contact Name",
          filterable: {
            cell: {
              operator: "contains"
            }
          },
          editor: NameAutoComplete


        }, {
          field: "ContactTitle",
          title: "Contact Title",
          filterable: {
            cell: {
              operator: "contains"
            }
          },
          editor: ContactTitleComboBox
        }, {
          field: "CompanyName",
          title: "Company Name",
          filterable: {
            cell: {
              operator: "contains"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          field: "Country",
          title: "Country",
          filterable: {
            cell: {
              operator: "contains"
            }
          }
          , editor: categoryDropDownEditor
        },

        {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"}
      ],
      height: 550,
      toolbar: ["create", "excel", "pdf"],
      excel: {
        fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
        proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
        filterable: true
      }, pdf: {
        allPages: true,
        fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf",
        proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
      },
      scrollable: false,
      pageable: true,
      sortable: true,
      groupable: true,
      filterable: {
        mode: "row"
      },
      editable: {
        mode: "inline",
        create: true,
        update: true,
        destroy: true
      }
    });
  });

  function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="Country" data-value-field="CustomerID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .width(100)
      .kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: {
          type: "odata-v4",
          transport: {
            read: "http://test.odata.northwind/odata/Customers"
          }

        }
      });
  }


  function NameAutoComplete(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="ContactName" data-value-field="CustomerID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoAutoComplete({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: {
          type: "odata-v4",
          transport: {
            read: "http://test.odata.northwind/odata/Customers"
          }
        }
      });
  }


  function ContactTitleComboBox(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="ContactTitle" data-value-field="CustomerID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: {
          type: "odata-v4",
          transport: {
            read: "http://test.odata.northwind/odata/Customers"
          }
        }
      });
  }
</script>
```

As shown Below when I press the update button, nothing happens, seems like the button doesn't even trigger

[image]

Below is some of the JSON result I bound to the grid

[image]

Here is how i am trying to get and add records to grid in webapi.

```
public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        readonly Model1 _db = new Model1();

        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 20)]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_db.Customers.AsQueryable());
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] string key)
        {
            return Ok(_db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(t => t.CustomerID == key));
        }
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Customers customer)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            _db.Customers.Add(customer);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(customer);
        }
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            var customers = await _db.Customers.FindAsync(key);
            if (customers == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _db.Customers.Remove(customers);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

I have been scratching my head all day, seems like I am missing something, any help would be appreciated

**UPDATED**
[image]

Comment: Can you check whether there are any errors in the browser while updating the data. You can use Developer tools is chrome for that.

Comment: There seems to be no error there , i have checked it. When i press update button while inserting record nothing happens

Comment: as far as i know there should be "update" property with its url in transport as like "read" and there should be "Put"(generally we add this method for update)....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not configured the grid to allow editing. Although you added the create button, you need to change the editable field to allow editing as follows:

```
editable: {
            mode: "inline",
            create: true,
            update: true,
            destroy: true
        }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I tried it still the update button doesn't trigger nor it gives any exception on the browser's console

Comment: Also I can see that you are missing the model field in the schema, you should put all the id and fields in the model and not outside. Something like this schema: {
                model: {
                    id: ...,
                    fields: {}
                }

Comment: I think now the button triggers some action, now when i press the button i see this error shown above in the last image attached. I have update the grid script above, changes you specified are in it.

Comment: I think the value's of the grid i am trying to add are not being passed to the odata service???

Comment: I can't really say whats wrong without details on the error but one thing seems obvious is the use of the format parameter and it is said that it would cause an error since it is not implemented in the WebApi OData, so try changing the code of the parameter map to the following: parameterMap: function (options, type) {
            var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
            delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter
            delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter
           return paramMap;
}

Comment: The above code is from an old telerik blog post http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-10-25/using_kendo_ui_with_mvc4_webapi_odata_and_ef. I am not sure if it is valid or not but might be of use to try